# Nuget CLI command not recognized and error comes while running commands in Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I want to pack my Visual studio class library project into a Nuget package and need to push to azure Artifacts feed.

But when I run command '*nuget restore*' in the Package Manager Console it says error as '*command not recognized....*'

Please let me know why the command is not recognized

Comment: Thanks. Done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the '*NuGet.CommandLine*' nuget package to make it work.